# Does .VBS support Hold-Wait program paradigm?

Tags: vbscript

Can the below programming structure is possible in VBScript.Where ProgA will start and after some lines of execution,it will give birth two procsses say ProgB and ProgC.When these child .vbs will be done,then Parent program ProgA will resume its execution and will finish its taks

```
                                    ProgA.VBS
                                        |
                 -------------------------------------------------
                 |                                               |
            ProgB.VBS                                        ProgC.VBS
```

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about then [.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [.Exec](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/subscriptions/index/ateytk4a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) methods of the WshShell object (`CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")`). Make sure you pay attention to the `bWaitOnReturn` parameter to .Run and the **.Status** (and **.Exitcode**) properties of the [WshScriptExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/subscriptions/index/2f38xsxe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) object. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13929920/603855) contains sample code for .Run and .Exec.

**Update:**

a.vbs (not production quality code!):

```
Option Explicit

Const WshFinished = 1

Dim goWSH : Set goWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim sCmd, nRet, oExec

sCmd = "cscript .\b.vbs"
WScript.Echo "will .Run", sCmd
nRet = goWSH.Run(sCmd, , True)
WScript.Echo sCmd, "returned", nRet

sCmd = "cscript .\c.vbs"
WScript.Echo "will .Exec", sCmd
Set oExec = goWSH.Exec(sCmd)
Do Until oExec.Status = WshFinished : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
WScript.Echo sCmd, "returned", oExec.ExitCode

WScript.Echo "done with both scripts"
WScript.Quit 0
```

.Runs b.vbs:

```
MsgBox(WScript.ScriptName)
WScript.Quit 22
```

and .Execs c.vbs:

```
MsgBox(WScript.ScriptName)
WScript.Quit 33
```

output:

```
cscript a.vbs
will .Run cscript .\b.vbs
cscript .\b.vbs returned 22
will .Exec cscript .\c.vbs
cscript .\c.vbs returned 33
done with both scripts
```

The MsgBoxes will prove that a.vbs waits for b.vbs and c.vbs.

**Update II - VBScript's MultiProcessing ((c) @DanielCook):**

ax.vbs:

```
Option Explicit

Const WshFinished = 1

Dim goWSH : Set goWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Each cmd holds the command line and (a slot for) the WshScriptExec
Dim aCmds : aCmds = Array( _
    Array("cscript .\bx.vbs", Empty) _
  , Array("cscript .\cx.vbs", Empty) _
)
Dim nCmd, aCmd
For nCmd = 0 To UBound(aCmds)
    ' put the WshScriptExec into the (sub) array
    Set aCmds(nCmd)(1) = goWSH.Exec(aCmds(nCmd)(0))
Next
Dim bAgain
Do
    WScript.Sleep 100
    bAgain = False ' assume done (not again!)
    For Each aCmd In aCmds
        ' running process will Or True into bAgain
        bAgain = bAgain Or (aCmd(1).Status <> WshFinished)
    Next
Loop While bAgain
For Each aCmd In aCmds
    WScript.Echo aCmd(0), "returned", aCmd(1).ExitCode
Next

WScript.Echo "done with both scripts"
WScript.Quit 0
```

.Execs bx.vbs

```
Do
  If vbYes = MsgBox("Tired of this rigmarole?", vbYesNo, WScript.ScriptName) Then Exit Do
  WScript.Sleep 300
Loop
WScript.Quit 22
```

and cx.vbs:

```
Do
  If vbYes = MsgBox("Tired of this rigmarole?", vbYesNo, WScript.ScriptName) Then Exit Do
  WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
WScript.Quit 33
```

Don't do this at work without a lot of further effort invested in error handling.

Comment: Can I have simple Demo code,which would show us that how prog A gave birth the two other processes from it, and then wait for those two to complete.When these two completed how the parent got communication and resumes its tasks-- a full programatic code as an Demo,May I have?

Comment: I already gave +1, but if the OP wants to actually run both b and c at "the same time". They'd just have to use the Exec method for both processes, and check the Status within the loop. (Only stating this for the OP.) Great answer.

Comment: Mind blowing @Ekkehard.Horner, i would realy like to implement this technique for my two .vbs codes,Which can be really started this way? any more care should I need with my one's if i implement this paradigm with my two's? :-)

Comment: can you both also vote up my post? :-) i think this would help others really more:-)

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner May i have some simple logic on the post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947199/merge-multiple-rows-in-a-single-row-depending-on-conditions-using-vbscript/13956382#comment19259368_13956382 ..please