# Merge multiple rows in a single row depending on conditions using VBScript

Tags: powershell, excel, vbscript, adodb, vba

Suppose, I have An Excel Matrix like below :

```
  EmpId   Empname   EmpAddrs    Hiredate    joiningdate   Salary   TypeOfWorker    BondOver   CurrentBU    reporting officer     Manager
    11      abc       eee        12/10          01/11       20K         "P"          Yes         ALP            MM                 PMO
    12      abc       tpt        10/10          01/11       10K         "T"           No         ATP            MM                 PMO
    82      abc       tpp        08/10          01/11       10K         "T"           No         ATP            MM                 OOP
    72      abc       tpp        08/10          01/11       10K         "P"           No         ATT            MM                 OOP
```

I Need to merge them all as below:

```
 Manager   EmpId   Hiredate    TypeOfWorker    CurrentBU    reporting officer   EmpId   Hiredate    TypeOfWorker    CurrentBU    reporting officer
   PMO       11     12/10         "P"            ALP             MM               12     10/10          "T"           ATP             MM
   OOP       82     08/10         "T"            ATP             MM               82     08/10          "P"           ATT             MM
```

Any Idea to implement the same? All employees having the same manager will be in one row with limited column values.

Thanks

Comment: Tukai! How can we help you today? :) If provided a VBA solution, will be happy to convert it to the Script?

Comment: Yes,I will convert it from my end>

Comment: @bonCodigo waiting for your idea! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the priviledge to be on full time here, but will help you. Will mssg you when ready. Otherwise let's hope another user can help you out :) here is a question to you, imagine if you have 100s of empid? Then your Excel sheet will not have enough column to merge them into one row. Then what do you do?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I couldn't understand how to frame this to code?

Comment: What's the logic for merging? Why was Emp Id 12 and 72 left out? Do you how to code in VBA?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Please scroll right to the window. It is there.Logic is all the employees under same manager will be merged in the same row,with their manger names.

Comment: Ok here is the logic (One way to do it)
`1.` Get the name of the Managers in a unique collection
`2.` Loop through the names and then filter your data
`3.` Once you have filtered the data, loop though the filtered data and copy the selected cells to the relevant area.
I can give you the code but I want you to give it a try and show the code that you tried and the error that you are facing (i.e if you get one) and we will take it from there...

Comment: @TukaiRakshit I think Siddharth's idea is a good one, please give a try first.  Step 1: Move Manager ID to the first column for convinence, Step 2: Add them into collection, Step 3: Filter the worksheet using each manager ID, `MOVE` the cells to the correct place

Comment: next step, delete the row you moved data from.

Comment: For example, moving data from "A2:D2" to "E1:H1" 

   Range("A2:D2").Cut Destination:=Range("E1")
   Rows(2).Delete shift:=xlUp

Comment: @TukaiRakshit I could see even Siddtharth has given you tips. Did you follow those?

Comment: @TukaiRakshit can you remove some of your comments which are not productive? Coz it makes so sore for anyone to go through it.;) BTW when you are merging you seem to remove `salary`, is that correct?

Comment: @bonCodigo not only salary,more columns I have deleted from the final output table!

Comment: @SiddharthRout could you please give me the code,I am totally in trouble with lots of codes,if i get your one,I can frame it.I am totally ended up with scripts and errors with them.So please!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the columns you don't need and export the table as CSV:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open "before.xlsx"

' delete columns, start with the rightmost column to avoid having to adjust
' positions
wb.Sheets(1).Columns("H:H").Delete
wb.Sheets(1).Columns("F:F").Delete
'...

wb.SaveAs "before.csv", 6
wb.Close False   ' b/c the file wasn't saved in Excel format
xl.Quit
```

Then convert it like this:

```
infile  = "before.csv"
outfile = "after.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(infile)

heading = f.ReadLine
data    = f.ReadLine

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  heading = heading & "," & heading
  data    = data & "," & f.Readline
Loop

f.Close

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(outfile, 2)
f.WriteLine heading
f.WriteLine data
f.Close
```

Then open the new CSV in Excel and save it as a workbook:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

numCols = ...    ' 

dataTypes = Array()
For i = 0 To numCols
  ReDim Preserve dataTypes(UBound(dataTypes))
  dataTypes(UBound(dataTypes)) = Array(i+1, 2)
Next

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.OpenText "after.csv", , , 1, 1, False, False, True, _
  , , , dataTypes
wb.SaveAs "after.xlsx"
wb.Close

xl.Quit
```

Of course these three steps can be combined into a single script, but I'm going to leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: the data is stored in an excel sheet. and the final arrangement would need to make to another sheet.

Comment: But one thing to remember that Manager whose don't have emploess should have an entry like the others who has the employees. for the employee manager in the excel row all the other column would need to be blank except the first column.

Comment: All the things should need to be happened via a script,as those data are dynamic in nature,which has been produced by another data.

Comment: Nice update and thought you have provided to me.But one thing to note here- Are the both .csv files got stored in the local disk?if so in which directory it would be saved?

Comment: As it is, the script(s) will be opened from or created in the current working directory. You need to modify the filenames/paths according to your requirements.

Comment: Okay,Then i want also to delete such files when one record will be saved in the excel.That means one merged row would get saved and delete those files and would create a new for new merge record.Can it be done this way?As those files can not be in the directory- will be useful as a temporary files. Can you do update your code accordingly,please?

Comment: can you explain `dataTypes = Array()` what does it do?

Comment: I just updated my description table to give you more idea on the reality of the table format.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thx0f315%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) covers deleting files quite well. Please do a little legwork yourself, will you?

Comment: `dataTypes = Array()` initializes `dataType` with an empty array. The fields of this array define the types of the imported columns.

Comment: Yes,I will.You did all,this little step I can do. :-) But I have a confusion that .csv file is saving one merged row at a time to the final excel.But in the next attempt when i will go to save the .csv finally ,it would overwrite the excel content- the merged sheet I am talking about.Am I right?

Comment: please help me to understand the above doubt!

Comment: `dataTypes(UBound(dataTypes)) = Array(i+1, 2)` what the empty array assigning to the dataTypes array?

Comment: My sample conversion script merges all rows into a single line before writing that line (plus an adjusted header line) to a new file. `Array(i+1, 2)` is not an empty array (that would be `Array()`). It's an array with 2 values: `i+1` and `2`. You provide the [FieldInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.opentext%28v=office.11%29.aspx) argument of `OpenText()` as an array of arrays, where the nested arrays contain the column number as the first, and the actual data type as the second value.

Comment: Could you please tell how the 4 rows will be converted to two rows  matrix,using your algorithm? I am not able to understand the logic,what you have tried to show you here.But i believe it is a great thought of the design,i have given to you. So that i can implement it in my actual requirement. :-)

Comment: here two or three rows will be merged in a single line,if their managers are same. Each rows describe the details of manager - employee relation information in this examples. I have added two more to the existing one,so that you can get a deeper view of the concept.