# Can a dictionary object have multiple Items under same key?

Tags: vbscript

I a looking for an workaround related to dictionary objects items

```
Dim a, d 'Create some variables

 Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

 d.Add "a", "Athens" 'is possible I know 

 d.Add "a", "Athens","India","Paris" ' Is this Possible  under same Key?
```

Description snapshot:(***UPDATED***)

```
  Manger ID            EMPID      EMPID     EMPID     EMPID ......

     11                12          10
     15                10 
     20                22          45        46
     40
```

How the above table can then be implemented using dictionary object? Give me some idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Makes variable name more OPfriendly

EDIT: Include a Scripting.Dictionary Reference for OP's [reading](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/A_3391-Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html)

```
Sub t()
    Dim d
    Dim a
    a = Array("Athens", "India", "Paris")
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add "a", a
    MsgBox Join(d.Item("a"), ",")
End Sub
```

EDIT: to read values as in OP's question into dictionary and retrieve the values

```
Sub t()
    Dim d As Object
    Dim values
    Dim height As Long
    Dim item
    Dim width As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MANGERID
    Dim EMPIDs
    Dim EMPID
    With ActiveSheet
        height = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If height < 2 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 2 To height
            width = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            if width > 1 then  'make sure have EMPID
                ReDim values(1 To width - 1)
                Key = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                For j = 2 To width
                    values(j - 1) = .Cells(i, j).Value
                Next j
                d.Add Key, values
            end if
        Next i

        'displaying back the items in the dictionary
        For Each MANGERID In d.keys
            'value array
            EMPIDs = d.item(MANGERID)
            If TypeName(EMPIDs) = "Variant()" Then
                For Each EMPID In EMPIDs
                    Debug.Print MANGERID & ":" & EMPID
                Next EMPID
            End If
        Next MANGERID

        Set d = Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you code the same for my updated description,which is dynamic in nature?

Comment: you mean your "Description snapshot:" part is the input excel part and you want to store them in dictionary?

Comment: Yes, Larry! you are right! and also want to see how to access those item,once all the Keys and Item are loaded into the Dictionary objects!

Comment: @TukaiRakshit A really good article to read about Dictionary
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/A_3391-Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html

Comment: I am not able to open now the link,my computer firewall blocking that.Can you post a demo code for the same?So that I can write down my requirement to code right now. please :-)

Comment: Sorry to bother you!I didn't see your post!

Comment: the EmpId s are in different cell of the object,Can you modify the code for that?

Comment: you mean they are NOT ALL Stored in Column B? Please provide the correct format in your question

Comment: please see my updated answer, 2nd code snippet. The change are some basic tech. in VBA/VBS. you should learn them.

Comment: Just one last question- I want the value from the dictionary object one at a time,like we are accessing the values in array.I need the value one at a time as I will use those values to my other calculations!

Comment: you want ONE Manger ID at a time or ONE EMPID at a time?

in my code, the `For Each Key In d.keys` is looping Manger ID
the `Value` is a array element storing the EMPID, you can loop `Value` as an array

Comment: One EMP ID I want to access for the Manager ID key from the Dic. object

Comment: see updated code, you can replace `debug.print` by `MsgBox` or some assignment statement

Comment: Perfect!! I am happy to get it learn from you.But one thing to not here,that I don't want to add the manager ID key which has no EMPID to dictionary object.Hope it is validated in your code,Like Manager ID= "40"

Comment: nope, honestly, you lack knowledge in many basic vba operation, I can suggest you some good readings later. AFK right now

Comment: Sure!! Please some VBA reference if you have,share me.I am totally new in this domain! Best of Luck :-)

Comment: why you used in the statement "ReDim values(1 To width - 1)" `1 to width-1`? why `1` ?

Comment: I specific  1 <--- meaning the starting index is from 1, personal habit, you can start from 0, -1, 2 e.t.c.

If you do no specific it , the default starting index is 0, e.g. redim values(width-1)  = redim values( 0 to width-1)

1 to width -1 --> total No. of element is (width -1), the first column is MANGERID.. so that's the -1

Comment: Okay! Got you. I kept it as your one.But out of curiosity As we redefined it to `1 to width-1` , so I am trying to access the O th value,Will it through `ERROR`

Comment: ys. It will return "Runtime Error 9" : Subscript out of range

Comment: Okay I am Done!!! Now no questions from my sides :-) on dictionary object if you have some references please share once you have time!

Comment: Can this problem be solved using dictionary objects? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947199/merge-multiple-rows-in-a-single-row-depending-on-conditions-using-vbscript#comment19237088_13947199

Comment: I am geeting an error on the line `ReDim values(1 To (width - 2))` or `ReDim values(1 To width - 2)` - Both tried. **ERROR** `Expected ')'` C an you check?

Comment: My code is width-1 not width-2..because my checking is width >1

Comment: In vbscript you cant use redim(a to b) syntax   . You need to change to redim values(width-2)    and shift all indice by one..   this is vba code.

Comment: For this kund of problem you should learn to isolate the problem .. write a vbs only cintaining that lune with fixed a to b..

Comment: may I have some idea from you on the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950959/excel-column-autofiltering-using-vbscript#comment19241909_13950959 post?

Comment: I m outdoor using mobile device . Will get back to you later

Answer (score 1):

No. By definition, dictionary data types use keys that must be unique. I know it's like this on most implementations, but the closest I can come to for an authoritative reference for VBscript's `Scripting.Dictionary` is this [TechNet blurb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176993.aspx#EGAA):

> A key is a unique entry: no two keys within a single Dictionary object can be the same.

Comment: I was looking for If the same key can contain multiple values or not?

Comment: I think in that case you would have a Dictionary of Arrays.

Comment: I updated subject description,Can you look into the same? and advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example for any others who view this and need another approach towards this solution. I feel this can be of help.

```
Dim objDictionary
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dicKey = 69
    dicValues = ""
    dicVal = "val1"
    dicVal2 = "val2"
    dicVal3 = "val3"
    objDictionary.add dicKey, DicValues1 & DicValues2
    chang = -1

if chang = -1 then  
    objDictionary.item(dicKey) = dicVal & "," & dicVal2
    chang = -69
end if

if chang = -69 then
    objDictionary.item(dicKey) = dicVal3 & ", " & dicVal & ", " & dicVal2
    chang = -1
end if

for each objDictionary_key in objDictionary.keys
    msgbox "Key: " & objDictionary_Key & " Value: " & objDictionary.item(objDictionary_Key)
next
```

I hope this helps some!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add more than one item in one key their would be the duplication of key and Vb Script does not allow it.
To know more information on dictionary object refer the following link.
[How To Use Dictionary Object](https://smarttipsqa.blogspot.com/2018/04/dictionary-object-in-qtpuft.html)