# Excel column autofiltering using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Suppose I have a matrix like below :

```
     EMPID    Type Of employment
   #1 10            "T"
   #2 11            "P"
   #3 20            "P"
   #4 40            "T"
   #5 50            "T"
   #6 15            "P"
   #7 19            "T"
```

***After Filtered***

```
    EMPID    Type Of employment
  #2 11            "P"
  #3 20            "P"
  #6 15            "P"
```

Can you people suggest me How to do it in vbscript? I know the syntax of VBA,but in VBScipt no idea how to format?

And after filtering If I use CountA on column#1 should I get the Row numbers as `3` or `7`?Too much confused I am here.

**UPDATE**

```
  objSheet2.Range("B1").AutoFilter 2, "Parent",,,False
```

***to remove auto-filtering i used the code -*** `objSheet2.Rows("1:1").Select.AutoFilter`     but getting an error `Unable to get the select property of the Range Class`

**Corrected**  `objSheet2.Range("B1").AutoFilter 2, "Parent",,,True`
               `objSheet2.AutoFilterMode = False`

***Query:*** once the rows are filtered,then how would I recognize the actuall row numers of the filtered data rows,when looping over them?

***ANSWER***

```
    For rowIndex=2 To objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob1.Columns(1))
    If objSheet2.Rows(rowIndex).Hidden Then
        ' do nothing - row is filtered out
    Else
        MsgBox(rowIndex)
    End If
    Next
```

This way I got the Filtered rows actual row number. Please advice if any better idea you guys post:-)

**Screen shot**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: maybe this will help you... because you seem to have a lot of questions about how to do things in `vbscript` with Excel, versus `VBA`. Once you establish the Excel object through `vbscript` the object model works the same as `VBA` ...  So, if you get the VBA syntax, you can apply write the XL object.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Please see my update! why it is set to false? It should be "ON" right? And I want to filtered values on column#1. So how should I make it? Because this syntax is not working in Vb-script.

Comment: have you read anything about `AutoFilter`. This would not do much of anything in vBA either, except place filters on columns A-D in row 1. Also, '.AutoFiltermMode = False` does turn off your filters. But sometimes you need to remove any existing filters before setting them again.

Comment: to actually filter on Column 1, you need to set the `column` and the `filter string` property in the `AutoFilter` method.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Please see my update above. And Now when my script will be done by its processing,how to revert it back?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman May I know when we are using filter set,What are the ways we can get the correct row numbers of the filtered values,suppose when i am looping?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Can you review my code please,If it is the adbvanced one,than please vote me up,or post a new one with your magical thought! :-)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman why you delete your post? you helped me that's big for me. i was just confirming myself,not more that that.and thought that to get reviewed by you!

Comment: okay. will open it up again.

Comment: I am junior than you in knowledge,So eager to learn from you guys.Please don't think i am giving challenge on your thought. if I did so forgive me :-(

Comment: @TukaiRakshit dude I did what you requested..., so you watch out next time.. ! :$

Comment: vote up here friend [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321645/how-the-description-mentioned-hashmethods-work-in-ruby#comment19905772_14321645) i need. Please do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will get you want you are after a little faster.

```
objSheet2.Range("B1").AutoFilter 2, "Parent",,,True 

Dim rngFilter as Range
Set rngFilter = objXL.Application.Intersect(objSheet2.UsedRange,objSheet2.UsedRange.Offset(1),objSheet2.Columns(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

msgbox "Filtered range has " & rngFilter.Rows.Count & " rows."
'do with the range as you wish.

Dim cel as objXL.Range 'or just leave this off
For each cel in rngFilter
   msgbox cel.row
Next

objSheet2.AutoFilterMode = False
```

In this way you are only selecting the visible cells after being filtered. You can then load that range into an array or loop through it as you see fit.

Comment: Yes,I understood your code,but partially.can you clarify that how would i get the original row number of the visible rows using the `Range` object? Please help me to understand!

Comment: But `For each cel in rngFilter msgbox cel.row Next` will not work in VBScript,as `For each ...In.. next` is not supported by VbScript.So any workaround for the same?

Comment: @TukaiRakshit -> it will work if you qualify it with the XL object, no?

Comment: I am talking about the `For` loop structure, the way you wrote VBScript never support such syntax. `For I=1 to N ... Next` is only supported by VBS.

Comment: `Dim cel as Range` also will not be supported,it supports only `Dim cel`.. That's the thing.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit -> okay, so take off the `Range` or add `objXL.Range`, as far as `vbscript` not supporting a `For Next` loop, I have no idea where you got that information ... see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_looping.asp).

Comment: please see the screenshot i just pasted in the description!

Comment: @TukaiRakshit -> really, do you even debug? what about just taking everything after as out? Did you even try that?

Comment: Thanks to open this up again. If my post seems to good you,please vote me up.:-)

Comment: May I have some idea on the below post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947199/merge-multiple-rows-in-a-single-row-depending-on-conditions-using-vbscript/13956382#comment19253062_13956382

Comment: could you please tell me Why `objSheet2.UsedRange.Offset(1)`? I got confused in this term of your code.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit -> it offsets the usedrange by 1 row. So, it won't pick up your header row in the range object.