# Error in Redim statement in Vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

For the below code I am getting following error: `Expected ')'`

```
**CODE**

  Set dicParentChild = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To height
        width = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob2.Columns(i))
      If width > 2 Then 
        ReDim values(1 To (width - 2))
        Key = ob2.Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 3 To width
            values(j - 2) = ob2.Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
        dicParentChild.Add Key, values
      End If
    Next i
```

Can any one please help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript's arrays are zero-based. To specify the size of an array, you must use `(Re)Dim a(LastIndexToUse)`. `(Re)Dim a(3)` will create an array containing 4 slots (indices: 0, 1, 2, 3).

VBA allows the specification of the first **and** the last index (using a `From To To` syntax).

So you must consider how many items you need, substract 1 to get the last index parameter for `(Re)Dim`, and be very carefull when you compute the array indices from your cell/row/col numbers.

Comment: But I changed the `code` to `ReDim values(1,(width - 2))`. And the error removed.So Will it work? means if I started to assign values from `values(1)`,will it through any error?

Comment: @TukaiRakshit - please use the docs for Arrays and (Re)Dim to learn - among lots of other interesting things - that ReDim values(1, 2) creates/re-structures a 2x3 two-dimensional array. Then use paper and pencil to plan your computations of array indices from the row/column numbers.

Comment: Got your point! Thanks for the right directions. VBA and VBS making me to confused to streamline my concepts :-)

Comment: Can I have some input on the post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950959/excel-column-autofiltering-using-vbscript#comment19241909_13950959  please