# Worksheet opening errors

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

when i am trying to get create an sheet object,getting the error:

```
    Dim oFS   : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oXls  : Set oXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oWb   : Set oWb  = oXls.Workbooks.Open(oFs.GetAbsolutePathName("Wing_To_Wing_Report.xlsx"))
    Dim aData ': aData    = oWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$A2:$C10")
    Dim dicP  : Set dicP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Range,ObSheet1,ObSheet2
    Dim TotalRows,LastCol


    ObSheet1=oWb.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WingToWingMay25")
    ObSheet2=oWb.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ParentChildLink")
```

Tried this also:

```
   ObSheet1=oWb.Worksheets("WingToWingMay25")
   ObSheet2=oWb.Worksheets("ParentChildLink")
```

**Error** Object doesn't support this property or method: "ActiveWorkbook"

Can you help me here? why so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. oWb itself is a workbook object  You don't need the `ActiveWorkbook`
   part
2. you miss the `set` keyword in  `set
   ObSheet1=oWb.Worksheets("WingToWingMay25")`

Also, I saw from one of your printscreen, you are using Notepad++ to develop,

Instead of just running the script directly,

please use a debugger to test the script.

You can find the debugger [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800794/excel-how-to-convert-bas-file-to-vbscript-exe-or-running-from-command-line/13802548#13802548)

Using the debugger, you can run the source code line by line,

and use the watch window to see the properties of each object at runtime.

Comment: Okay,Thanks I will use that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can I have some help on the post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947199/merge-multiple-rows-in-a-single-row-depending-on-conditions-using-vbscript/13956382#comment19259368_13956382

Comment: Can you help me in the above post?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ObSheet1=oWb.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WingToWingMay25")` , you should do this :

```
set ObSheet1=oWb.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WingToWingMay25")
```