# I am trying to copy the sheet1 range data to sheet2 range but,nothing copied

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am trying to copy the sheet1 range data to sheet2 range but nothing gets copied. This is the full code which I was trying to achieve something but got stuck in the basic place. Please help

**Edit:** I tried the Macro just now and the same thing happened with this code. Please see the snapshot where you can see that Snap 1 contains source data and also selected but does not get copied to Snap 2. However the ranges are selected there.

```
  Sub copy()
      Range("A1:J4").Select
      Selection.copy
      Sheets("Sheet2").Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      ActiveWorkbook.Save
  End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

***UpDate***

*Style-1*

```
     Option Explicit


     Dim objSheet1,objSheet2,TotalRows,TotalcolCopy,strPathExcel1

     Dim oXls  : Set oXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     Dim aData ': aData = oWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$A2:$C10")
     Dim dicP  : Set dicP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

     strPathExcel1 = "D:\WIPData\AravoMacro\Finalscripts\GE_Wing_To_Wing_Report.xlsx"
     oXls.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1

     Set objSheet1 = oXls.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
     Set objSheet2 = oXls.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)


     TotalRows=oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(objSheet1.Columns(1)) - 3
     TotalcolCopy=oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Parent Business Process ID", objSheet1.Rows(3), 0)

   objSheet1.Range(objSheet1.Cells(4,1),objSheet1.Cells(TotalRows,TotalcolCopy)).Copy(objSheet2.Range("A1"))

    '=======================
     oXls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPathExcel1
     oXls.Workbooks.close
     oXls.Application.Quit
    '======================
```

*Style-2*

```
  Option Explicit


  Dim objSheet1,objSheet2,TotalRows,TotalcolCopy,strPathExcel1
  Dim oFS   : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim oXls  : Set oXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Dim aData ': aData    = oWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$A2:$C10")
  Dim dicP  : Set dicP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  oXls.Workbooks.Open(oFs.GetAbsolutePathName("Test.xlsx"))
  Set objSheet1 = oXls.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  Set objSheet2 = oXls.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)


  TotalRows=oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(objSheet1.Columns(1)) - 3
  TotalcolCopy=oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Parent Business Process ID", objSheet1.Rows(3), 0)

  objSheet1.Range(objSheet1.Cells(4,1),objSheet1.Cells(TotalRows,TotalcolCopy)).Copy(objSheet2.Range("A1"))

  '=======================
  oXls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Test.xlsx"
  oXls.Workbooks.close
  oXls.Application.Quit
  '======================
```

Could you people tell me what differences between Style-1 and Style-2.Because in Style-1 all the copied data get saved,which is not the case in Style-2. This design issue mainly the overall problem i was facing from morning.

In what way Style-2 is not perfect?

Comment: @Larry i got the help from the link [Enable Macro in excel 2010](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/enable-all-macros-in-excel-2010/)

Comment: Now everything is cool !! :-)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout can you help me here? - "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947199/merge-multiple-rows-in-a-single-row-depending-on-conditions-using-vbscript/13956382#comment19259368_13956382"

Comment: just a matter of Enabling? very well :)

Comment: no @bonCodigo the problem still remains,Today i started with Excel-2010 to work and the problem arose.Earlier I worked with Excel-2003(.xls)

Comment: @bonCodigo Can you check my updated description and tell me the root cause?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why style-1 is perfect,Style-2 not? both are looking ok,but in practice they are giving different output!

Comment: @bonCodigo could you say what the hidden error in between Style-1 and Style-2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to copy from one range to another would be to **recoding** macro. Looking at your code, what are the values you are getting for `TotalRows` and `LastCol`? **Assuming you have matching data returned from your `Match()`, so there're rows to copy`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPastes()
    Dim rng1 as Range
    Dim rng2 as Range

    Set rng1 = Sheets(1).Range("B2:C12")
    Set rng2 = Sheets(2).Range("B2")
    rng1.Copy
    rng2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

So in your case, can you keep it simple? Remove the following line. Just specify the starting Range of the Sheet2 and try out. You do not have to worry about `resize` at this point.

replace this,

```
ObSheet2.Range(ObSheet2.Cells(4,1),ObSheet2.Cells(TotalRows,LastCol)).PasteSpecial
```

with either: coz you are missing paste special argument

```
ObSheet2.Range(ObSheet2.Cells(4,1),ObSheet2.Cells(TotalRows,LastCol)) _ 
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

or : here without any fancy cells, but direct range

```
ObSheet2.Range(ObSheet2.Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: totalrows are the last filled data rows and the LastCol is the column number up to which i want the data to copy.But script has ended its run,and I opened the excel found that the range are selected in green but the second sheet has no data into it. I used the same for other scripts also,but here it is not worked. My bad! Why so can you tell me?

Comment: @TukaiRakshit are you sure it's returning any data after matching?

Comment: Yes I tried `ObSheet1.Range(ObSheet1.Cells(4,1),ObSheet1.Cells(TotalRows,LastCol)).Copy` and `ObSheet2.Range(ObSheet2.Cells(1,1),ObSheet2.Cells(TotalRows,LastCol)).PasteSpecial(-4163)` but no result.

Comment: But When I am doing copy manually,it works but through script doesn't work. Please help me.Its like a "Rain" without "cloud".

Comment: @TukaiRakshit what do you mean when you do manually it works? What is manual? Running a recorded macro? Can you just try in your script a plain copy paste (not manual) without any matches and so on?

Comment: Yes I did. Does the issue related Excel application or what? Manual means I select and copy and Paste by my hand. It works then.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit By all means I was not referring to manual by hand copying, I expected at least a mini macro.. If the issue is in Excel application. Get a new workbook and try out a simple copy paste macro recording. Then add the `match` and test again.

Comment: I have given the full code of mine,till now i developed. Can you check if there itself any issue.I tried this with multiple workbooks ,for no one it helped me.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit I mentioned to two steps. Have you followed that? 1. Get a new workbook and do a sample test using a simple copy paste macro 2. If that succeeds, you may incorporate the `match` 3. if all good then do the fancy cell references or whatever. You are not going anywhere just keeping your code.

Comment: Please see my `Edit`.I just tried this macro,and that small also not worked,like my script also.Attached two snaps are the same happening with my previous script. snap1 source sheet from where i have to copy,and you can see that Macroo has select the range and also in snap2 selects destination range where to paste,but no data.All are blanks.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit ok, let's do this slow, I assume the code you **EDIT** is recorded by macro, you need to run this macro by {F5} and since `Range("A1:J4").Select` Do not have the sheet's name specified, you need to make sure you are in Sheet1 or whatever sheet you have data in "A1:J4" range.

Comment: @bonCodigo could you please help me here to understand the issue?

Comment: i don't know @bonCodigo who did this! wait immediately i would accept your one!